# Use the PMI to prove that $(1+a)^n\ge an,\ \forall a>0,\ a\in \mathbb R $ and $n\ge 1,\ n\in \mathbb Z$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I know I can use the Bernoulli's Inequality or binomial theorem to directly deduce this, but my question here is how to use the PMI to directly show this inequality without any help from other theorem.

Let me omit the base case here, and here is what I did for the inductive step.

Suppose that $(1+a)^k\ge ak$, and we want to show that $(1+a)^{k+1}\ge a(k+1)$.

Then $(1+a)^{k+1}=(1+a)^k(1+a)\ge ak(1+a)=ak+a^2k+a-a=a(k+1)+a(ak-1)$, and here goes my confusion. Since all I know is that $a>0$ and $k>1$, it is not guaranteed that $(ak-1)>0$, so I can not just say that $a(k+1)+a(ak-1)>a(k+1)$. But I know this inequality must be correct. So can anyone show me how to properly prove the $k+1$ case?

Moreover, I think the reason why this happens is that in the $k+1$ case, at the first inequality, I zoomed $(1+a)^{k+1}$ too far to $ak(1+a)$ which  could be smaller than what we want to prove. So I am wondering if it is possible to find somewhere in between $(1+a)^{k+1}$ and $ak(1+a)$ so that the $k+1$ case is automatically true.

Comment: Are you sure you're not supposed to be showing that $(1+a)^k \ge 1+ak$, with the $1$ on the right-hand side?

Comment: @GregMartin I am pretty sure it is just $ak$ on the right hand side. Otherwise it can be showed easily.

Comment: The standard proof of Bernoulli uses induction, and is stronger (adding $1+$ to the right side) and applies for $a>-.$

Comment: @AndyZ If you can show the inequality is true for $1+ak$ then, since $1+ak\gt ak$, you are done.

Comment: I think the OP wants to solve this problem without using the "simpler" proof. However I think this doesn't work 100% with induction as I mentioned in my answer below

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yep I am aware of that, but how to show this weaker one with the PMI but without using that result you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

$$(1+a)^{k+1}=(1+a)^k(1+a)=(1+a)^k+a(1+a)^k > ak+a$$

Comment: Brilliant man! lol thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

If $a>1$ then we can simplify

$ak+a^2k=a(k+ak)> a(k+1)$

Otherwise if $a<1$ and $ak\geq 1$ we get

$ak+a^2k\geq ak+1\cdot a= a(1+k)$

Let's look at the last case with $a<1,ak<1$: In that case you can't use your induction argument, as you already mentioned that you can't guarantee that $ak-1>0$.

Take $a=1/4, k=2$. Then using the induction hypothesis would give that the LHS $\geq 1/4\cdot 2(1+1/4)= 5/8$ but we should show that LHS $=1/4(2+1)=3/4=6/8>5/8$. That is a contradiction.

What does that mean? It means that you can't use the induction argument for$ak<1$, but the statement is still valid, as it is a relaxation of the original lower bound of $ak +1$. But you need some other technique for proving correctness for $ak<1$

Edit: In that case you can simplify it as follows:
$$(1+a)^k(1+a) > 1+a > ak+a= a(k+1)$$

Comment: You are right but I think the reason why this happens is that in the $k+1$ case, at the first inequality, I zoomed $(1+a)^{k+1}$ too far to $ak(1+a)$ which as you said could be smaller than what we want to prove. So I am wondering if it is possible to find somewhere in between $(1+a)^{k+1}$ and $ak(1+a)$ so that the $k+1$ case is automatically true.

Comment: I've added the solution for the special case as well.